# Regex to match 0 or an even number of consecutive characters?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I'm looking to see if it's possible to have a regex pattern that matches content between enclosing single quotes in a string, with the requirement that single quotes are escaped using another single quote.

Example:

`The quick 'brown fox ''jumped ''''over the lazy dog''';`

The regex should capture this string: `'brown fox ''jumped ''''over the lazy dog'''`. Since a single quote is escaped using another single quote here, the rest of the string isn't included.

This is what I have so far `(?<!\')\'(?!\').+(?<!\')\'(?!\')`

This almost works, except the group isn't captured if the closing non-escaped single quote has an escaped quotes before it.

Is it possible to change the negative lookbehind to say that a single quote should be matched if there are either 0 or an EVEN number of single quotes behind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex without any look around:

```bash
'((?:[^']+|'')*)'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FOclPu/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `'`: Match a `'`
- `(`: Start a capture group

  - `(?:`:

    - `[^']+`: Match 1+ of any char that is not a `'`
    - `|`: OR
    - `''`: Match a pair of quotes i.e. `''`
  - `)*`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `)`: End capture group
- `'`: Match a `'`

Answer (score 3):

I think it can also be [unrolled](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#unrolled_staralt):

```
'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LcEyah/1)

- `[^']*` matches [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of characters [that are not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a single quote
- `(?:` [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) `)` for repeating what's inside

Comment: ++ for the unrolled variant. However if requirement is to not to match an empty string like `''` then this pattern can become a bit tricky.